# Reduce form groups layout in Twig with Symfony2(.7)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, twig

I am trying to get rid of repeating layouts in twig for symfony2 forms
Currently my layout looks something like :

```
<form name="step2" method="post" action="" class="productForm">
    <h2>Step2:</h2>

    <div id="step2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-widget">
                <div id="step2_client1">
                    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="step2_client1_clientTitle">Client 1 title:</label>

                        <div class="form-widget"><select id="step2_client1_clientTitle" name="step2[client1][clientTitle]" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                            <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                            <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                            <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
                            <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
                        </select></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="step2_client1_firstName">Client 1 first name:</label>

                        <div class="form-widget"><input type="text" id="step2_client1_firstName" name="step2[client1][firstName]" required="required" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label required" for="step2_client1_surname">Client 1 last name:</label>

                        <div class="form-widget"><input type="text" id="step2_client1_surname" name="step2[client1][surname]" required="required" class="form-control"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        ...
        
        <div class="form-group form-group-submit">
            <div class=""><a id="step2_save" class="has-spinner btn btn-default btn-submit"><span class="spinner"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>Complete the quote
            </a></div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="step2__token" name="step2[_token]" class="form-control" value="xxx"></div>
</form>
```

And I have a dirty js script to fix my layout in the way I want it to showup but this is, as said, dirty. So I was wondering if someone can help me alter my twig file to only show form-group and form-widget css classes for children elements and not for the parents.

The dirty js script:

```
$('.form-group').each(function(e){
    if($(this).parents('.form-group').length) {
        var $realGroup = $(this).parents('.form-group');
        $realGroup.toggleClass('form-group');
        $realGroup.children('.form-widget').toggleClass('form-widget');
    }
});
```

And the twig bit:

```
{% block form_row -%}
    {% spaceless %}
    <div class="form-group{% if (not compound or force_error|default(false)) and not valid %} has-error{% endif %}">
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        <div class="form-widget">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock form_row %}
```

Now the twig bit is the standard SF2 bootstrap form layout, I'm pretty sure i didn't alter that.

So any help getting rid of the js script and actually doing it in twig would be great, I have tried a few things but every single one of them turned out worse then what I did with js, So I'm a bit stuck.

**EDIT:**

What the js script does, is just removing the css classes, so the layout works. It would look flat because it would just be empty div's, but what I am after is not showing the divs in the first place. I'm trying to alter the twig script, not the css, as that is just the way we want it.

Comment: Are you just trying to target specific sections of your form with CSS? Because if so then using [child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) would surely be easier?

Comment: I re-read that 3 times and I have no idea what you are saying (in relation tot his example) i'm not tryinto to target anything with css, i just down want any nested forms, just plain forms, so if they  are nested, i dont want the parents to show up, as in `if form_row.hasChildren()` no html is outputted for that parent row.

Comment: Right, gotcha, that's not at all clear from your question because you're mentioning CSS classes and the bit of JavaScript you posted is toggling CSS classes so I was trying to get at the root of your question i.e. what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Fair enough, i'll update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options.

1.Either create each field manually:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path(''), 'attr': {'class':'productForm'}}) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.clientTitle, 'Client 1 title:', {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label required'}}) }}
    <div class="form-widget">
        {{ form_widget(form.clientTitle, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control' }}) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_errors(form.clientTitle) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.firstName, 'Client 1 first name:', {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label required'}}) }}
    <div class="form-widget">
        {{ form_widget(form.firstName, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control' }}) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_errors(form.firstName) }}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.firstName, 'Client 1 last name:', {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label required'}}) }}
    <div class="form-widget">
        {{ form_widget(form.firstName, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control' }}) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_errors(form.firstName) }}
</div>


<div class="form-group form-group-submit">
    <div class="">
        <a id="step2_save" class="has-spinner btn btn-default btn-submit">
            <span class="spinner">
                <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
            </span>
            Complete the quote
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

{{ form_end(change_password) }}
```

2.Or you could create your own [form theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes).

3.Or use a loop for each form:

```
{% for child in form.children %}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(child, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label required'}}) }}
        <div class="form-widget">
        {{ form_widget(child, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control' }}) }}
        </div>
        {{ form_errors(child) }}
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

It all depends on how many fields your future forms will have and how many similar forms you have.

However, using JS for such a thing is a no-no.

Comment: Yes i know that, however what you have seen is only a small portion of the form and there is about 30+ forms with more then 40 fields each, they all work fine but a manual solution is not going to happen, creating my form theme is all well and good but that still doesn't solve the issue of knowing when the row is top-level or not

Comment: What is a top-level row? Would be an idea to show before and after desired effect. Also, have you taken a look at [form collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) ? Maybe you could get an idea.

Comment: Before and after... the js does tell exactly that. And a toplevel row would be a form_row not nested in other rows.

Comment: nounty was auto awarded but i never got my question answered, i think it was clear enough what i needed but no1 never gave me a exact solution

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to create a custom form theme.

If you look [at the current Symfony2's bootstrap one](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig#L180), you can see:

```
{% block form_row -%}
    <div class="form-group{% if (not compound or force_error|default(false)) and not valid %} has-error{% endif %}">
        {{- form_label(form) -}}
        {{- form_widget(form) -}}
        {{- form_errors(form) -}}
    </div>
{%- endblock form_row %}
```

The "copound" stuff is actually telling you if the current element contains sub-elements (form, collection, ... basically all parent elements), and if you don't want to have that `form-group` class for parents, you just need to overload this block in a custom theme.

```
{# AppBundle::custom_theme.html.twig #}

{% use "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" %}

{% block form_row -%}
    <div class="{% if not compound %}form-group{% endif %}{% if (not compound or force_error|default(false)) and not valid %} has-error{% endif %}">
        {{- form_label(form) -}}
        {{- form_widget(form) -}}
        {{- form_errors(form) -}}
    </div>
{%- endblock form_row %}
```

If you don't want the div at all, just remove it! That's your go now.

---

To apply the change in your whole project, you can add this in `config.yml`:

```
twig:
    # ...
    form_themes:
        - 'AppBundle::custom_theme.html.twig'
```

Or to use it on a specific view only:

```
{% form_theme yourForm 'AppBundle::custom_theme.html.twig' %}
```

Note: `yourForm` is your current form object.

Comment: thanks for the answer but do you notice any difference between my form row (the twig bit) and your block form_row ? because that twig bit is located in `Acme/MyBundle/Resources/views/Form/form_horizontal_layout.html.twig` and is already extending the bootstrap form theme, what I am looking for is a way to tell if there are children forms in the row or not, because if there are, then i don't want to show the divs for that form row's layout, only the deepest form row in those nested forms should be visible as a div, as in flatten the nested form

Answer (score 1):

Already George Irimiciuc helped you, my point is that you can use 2nd option provided in George answer, you need to focus on this part of form theme.

Symfony2 twig create form based on selected theme, if you will try to add your form theme then it will be good, others option means you are just pushing problem to other place and that's just a trick. No need to update complete form them, just add your form_row it will work, can try this

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#customizing-the-form-row

I used this is my project, best point is that you can send attributes from your form builder which fields and then check those under form_row, which render your form rows and can create form like you want like after check conditions -

```
attr => array( 'parent_class' => false)
```

and can check this under form_row like

```
if( form.vars.attr.parent_class is defined )
```

and can add condition in twig.

If you have problem like your form has child form and twig form_row is showing that in odd way -

I build this project and only this till now, In that there is student entity joined with various entities so at time of form entries like Profile. I used both entity Student and Address what i did is, i just checked this

```
 {% if ( not form.children ) or ( form.vars.expanded is defined  and form.vars.expanded ) %}
  <div class="{{ form.vars.attr['parent-div-class'] is defined ? form.vars.attr['parent-div-class'] : 'col-sm-12'}}">
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form_label(form) }}
      {{ form_widget(form) }}
      {% if form_errors(form) %}
         {{ form_errors(form) }}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
   </div>    
{% else %}
    <div class="clear-both"></div>
    {{ form_label(form) }}           
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{% endif %}
```

code is not exact like this but main concept is.

Hope you understand my point.

Comment: the twig bit in my question is located at `Acme/MyBundle/Resources/views/Form/form_horizontal_layout.html.twig`. is that not my own layout ? i know i have to extend the form into my own theme, but what I am really after is how to tell in twig that the row has child forms or not

Comment: can try this - {% if ( not form.children ) or ( form.vars.expanded is defined  and form.vars.expanded ) %}