# Symfony2 Input file photo preview

Tags: php, symfony, file-io, photo, symfony-forms

I have a form in Symfony2 and in a form i have a photo input field where after upload a photo file give me the path but i would to show the preview about photo uploaded..

This is the code of the add in the form  :

```
->add('photo','file',array(
                'attr' => array("class"=>"filestyle", 
                                "data-iconName"=>"glyphicon-inbox",
                                "data-buttonText"=>"Scegli foto..",
                                "data-buttonName"=>"btn-primary",
                                "data-iconName"=>"glyphicon-folder-open"),
                'label'=>'user.file.label',
                'required'=>false,
                )
 )
```

How can i do for use the method **onChange** or can you give me the method for  to show the preview of photo uploaded?? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You are storing file to someplace and then storing that path to database so you need to add condition for this, to display image.

You can pass image value attribute from you form with PhotoImage(file) (i am assuming your entity name is Photo) entity like this

```
'value' => file_exists(IMAGE_PATH.$builder->getData()->getPhotoImage()) ? $builder->getData()->getPhotoImage() : false )
```

here

```
$builder->getData()->getPhotoImage()
```

gives you your PhotoImage entity value if any and

```
IMAGE_PATH
```

is constant which store your root path.

now your code is sending photo path to your form now you have to get that path and display to customer, for this condition in your twig file so that you can check if value is false or not.

for this you have to render your custom form theme like described here just add this code like written bellow - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903667/reduce-form-groups-layout-in-twig-with-symfony2-7/33018457#33018457)

```
{% if form.vars.block_prefixes[1] == "file" %}
    <div class="file-box" {% if form.vars.attr.value is not defined or form.vars.attr.value %}style="background:url('{{form.vars.attr.value}}')"{% endif %}></div> 
{% endif %}         
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_label(form) }}

{% if form_errors(form) %}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
{% endif %}
```

`form.vars.block_prefixes[1] == 'file'` will check if it's input type file or not.

`<div class="file-box">` will display your image if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nikhil Chaudhary answer, you can shows it in form:

```
{% if form.photo.vars.block_prefixes[1] == "file" and form.photo.vars.data %}
    <img style="max-width: 100px" src="{{ asset(form.photo.vars.data) }}">
{% endif %}
```

You do not need check file, because the input is file, so can remove

```
form.photo.vars.block_prefixes[1] == "file"
```

block from code.

BUT if you wan't to show on change, use jQuery lib or custom function(s), [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21164591/2110778).